# Making bootstrap 3 fixed footer with slide Up content?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make fixed footer in Bootstrap 3, but click on icon, i want someother div to apper, and add opacity to content body. This can be easy added by class fixed, but how to add opacity to content, and to add that slide up element.

The problem is that i dont know how big content inside that element will be, sometimes it will be long content, sometimes small, that is minor problem..

This is screenshoot what i need to make

[image]

Now when someone click on ACTION i need this

[image]

Can this be done by boostrap JS, or need some custom JS and css

Here if similar solution but just on smaller screens

http://www.bootply.com/103653

Here what i have for now, but i have problem to add opacity to content on clik on action

**CSS**

```
#accordion {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    border-radius:none !important;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    z-index:1030;
}
.opacity{
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="opacity"></div>
<div class="panel-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="accordion">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading clearfix">
  <h4 class="panel-title text-center"><a class="pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"> ACTION </a> <br>
<a class="pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo"> ACTION2 </a></h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">


HERE GOES THE CONTENT

</div>
<div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
Lorem Ipsum је једноставно модел текста који се користи у штампарској и словослагачкој индустрији. Lorem ipsum је био стандард за модел текста још од 1500. године, када је непознати штампар узео кутију са словима и сложио их како би направио узорак књиге. Не само што је овај модел опстао пет векова, него је чак почео да се користи и у електронским медијима, непроменивши се. Популаризован је шездесетих година двадесетог века заједно са листовима летерсета који су садржали Lorem Ipsum пасусе, а данас са софтверским пакетом за прелом као што је Aldus PageMaker који је садржао Lorem Ipsum верзије.

</div>
</div>
</div>

<footer class="container-fluid" role="contentinfo">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="navbar-inner navbar-content-center"> Copyright </div>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

And here is full example on fiddle

**http://jsfiddle.net/k4xt4g40/**\

I got problem with opacity, how to add when collapse is visble and when dont remove?

Got something like this

**http://jsfiddle.net/k4xt4g40/2/**

Only problem is that it it must stay display block when another action is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

You could use bootstrap for the stylizing and custom jquery scripts to implement the page disable and the menu expand features.

check out this fiddle [Navbar](http://www.bootply.com/54tSrVnUeK)

The navbar closed automatically becos of an error in the css class name you used in the bottom nav bar,

rename like below in the button

```
data-target=".navbar-collapse" to data-target=".navbar-collapse-bottom"
```

and

```
<div class="navbar-collapse-bottom collapse">
```

hope this solves your problem

Comment: Nice :) If i know how :(

Comment: that was the wrong fiddle sorry, here's the correct one [navbar](http://www.bootply.com/54tSrVnUeK)

Comment: Good, nice way, but the problem is here that i have another menu on the top!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60224/discussion-between-sidharth-and-gorostas).